# Simple AND/OR validation rule logic question

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to write a validation rule that says if the Stage is set to Lost, then if Lost Date, Why Lost, or both fields are not populated an error is returned. Here's what I have, but it's not working quite right...

```
AND(

ISPICKVAL( Stage__c , "Lost"),

OR(

(ISBLANK( Why_Lost__c )),
(ISBLANK( Lost_Date__c ))))
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Seems correct, you have some redundant parentheses but other than that... What is not working right? Is your rule never firing?

Comment: Try using LEN(Why_Lost__c) = 0 vs ISBLANK( Why_Lost__c )

Comment: I think problem in parentheses.please remove parentheses for both ISBLANK functions. @user34680

Comment: Removing the parenthesis, resolved your problem?

Comment: Removing () worked, thank you! trying to figure out how to mark as correct answer now  :)  cheers

Comment: @Pavantej can you add your comment as an answer so it can be marked as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @user34680 i thought my suggestion is resolved your problem.Please accept my solution and close the question.

please remove parentheses for both ISBLANK functions.

Comment: Pavan -- Please see [Etiquette](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed/2128#2128) for soliciting user answer acceptance